# Two Column Restriction for Parameters Section Chokes on Rich Formatting

Tags: discussion, documentation, formatting

It seems that the strict two-column restriction chokes on rich formatting in general, even when all of the formatting and content is contained in a two-column layout. See [this draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/drafts/33323):

[image: Two-column restriction hates everything pretty]

Comment: Create a new topic that explores this more substantially and add that to remarks on your shallow topic?

Comment: @Braiam it certainly seems like that might be the intended way to use topics. Maybe this is all a case of misunderstanding, on my part - I'll give that format a run O.o

Comment: Two columns are okay as long as complex formatting can be displayed without errors in it.

Comment: @Trilarion I've come to agree. I've updated the question to focus solely on this issue.